# Footer overlapping content/article

Tags: html, css, footer

I have this issue in my HTML/CSS where the footer overlaps the article content.
Yes I have been searching the web and nothing seems to work, I hope you know what is wrong with it.
I made a codepen here:
[CodePen LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYNgBX)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to me site</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Katte</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Geolocation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
        <article>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="paragraph">
                If you xxx give up, you will achieve nothing. Practice won’t get you anywhere if you mindlessly xxx practice the same thing. Change only occurs when you work deliberately with purpose toward a goal. Sometimes it is appropriate to place various typographic elements on the outside of the xxx left margin of text to maintain a strong vertical axis. This practice is referred to as exdenting and is most often used with bullets and quotations. While having drinks with Tibor Kalman one night, he told me, “When you make something no one hates, no one xxx loves it.” Don’t xxx 
            </p>
            <br>
            <p>Kunne du lide Lorem Ipsum?</p>
            <form action="First Name">
                Navn: <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Jesper">
            <br><br>
            <p>Hvor godt kunne du lide det på en skala fra 0 til 100?</p>
            <input type="range" name="range">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2>Katte video</h2>
            <video width="400" controls>
                <source src="Kitty.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </article>

        <article>
            <h2>One Fine Circle Son!</h2>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
    <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
</script> 
</article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p><small> Jesper Andersen</small></p>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/2000px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" width="70">
        <p><small> Copyright 2015</small></p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because u made it as `position:fixed`. Change it to `position:relative`

Comment: Try the `position:relative`.

Comment: Just remove the `position:fixed` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `position:fixed`. Change it to `position:relative`.

```
 footer{
        clear: both;
        font-size: 20px;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,  0,  0,  0.7);
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Oxygen';
        position: relative; 
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQvRbo